# How to save current date in a cookie with PHP and read it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I need to save current date in a cookie using PHP so it's readable from javascript.

I'm wondering how to do it since there are a lot of ways and formats of getting the date in PHP and I'm not sure which one will be the easiest to read in javascript, the most important thing for my implementation is that I need to be able to check with plain JS how much time has passed since the cookie's creation (it's value actually).

I already have a readCookie() function that get's a cookie's value, so my question is only about saving and retrieving (and maybe parsing) the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php:

```
$date = new DateTime();
setcookie("timestamp", $date->getTimestamp());
```

js:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
     }
}

var timestamp = getCookie('timestamp');
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: getCookie function can be replaced by other function which get cookie data, i.e $.cookie

Comment: great, I implemented it with no problems, could you tell me how to compare it with current date? (see how many days passed)

Comment: @Liso22 Use `var days_passed = (new Date() - date)/86400000`. `86400000` is the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: @Barmar what about rounding? 
~~((new Date() - date) / 86400000)

Comment: If they want rounding, use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use the RFC 2822 formatted date, which is `date('r')` in PHP. Or use `microtime()` which returns the number of miliseconds since 1/1/1970.

Then use the [Date object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in Javascript to create a Date object you can modify and figure how how much time has passed.

Answer (score -2):

cookies are saved on the browser
so using jquery cookie plugin can work for you

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question. He's asking how to store the value of the cookie so he can use it to handle date transformations. Seems like he understands how to read a cookie.